# Developer Trust App No Internet Connection Error ios

Tags: xcode

Have problem with trust developer app on iphone. There is no internet connection error, but internet is working well. Tried Wifi, celular data and nothing helps me.
I cannot verify any app from developers - mine from xcode and others like tutuapp etc..

Is it ppq.apple.com down (I see the following error -

> Http/1.1 Service Unavailable

or this is only mine problem ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes its down.  See the pictures below .

[image]

Comment: So verify developer apps on ios is it not working now? Or there is some other way to trust them?

Comment: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26991792/Internally-Generated-SSL-Cert-works-with-IE-does-not-work-with-FireFox.html